# What color clothes to use on altar for placing idol in Satyanarayana puja at home?

Tags: puja, satyanarayana

Whenever I do puja at home I place a small table on which idol is placed. And before placing idol I cover the table with a Red cloth. But recently I came across a Satyanarayana puja and saw that the idol was placed on a white cloth. So I asked the priest is it necessary to place on white cloth, or can we use red cloth also?
The priest only said for Durga puja we use Red cloth, but for Satyanarayana puja we use White / Yellow clothes.
I started to find relevance of this argument on internet, but came across no standard answer of Do's and Dont's. Can you please point me to some relevant text from where this can be verified.

Comment: Lord Vishnu is Pitambari. who likes yellow clothes. This could be reason.

Comment: What do you mean by idol? Please let me know. I also does SatyaNarayan katha every purnima but I don't know anything about Idol.

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks for pointing this out, this can explain one logic. But I am still looking for reason why we cannot use Red clothes.

Comment: @Rishabh I am talking about the idol of Vishnu or in my case our priest bring Shaligram to be placed on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such there are no specific instruction in the katha of Satyanarayana hence we have to go by normal way of worship of Sri Vishnu.

If you want to use different clothes for every pooja then you should use as per the day of the week.

If you want to use fixed color then yellow would be a better one as Thursday and its rules by Jupiter which is related Lord Vishnu.

White color is prescribed for almost all the deities and also for Lord Vishnu as mentioned in the famous verse. शुक्लाम्बरधरं विष्णुं शशिवर्णं चतुर्भुजम् ।प्रसन्नवदनं ध्यायेत् सर्वविघ्नोपशान्तये ॥

There is another opinion I found in ISCKON [website](http://www.iskcondesiretree.com/group/deityworship/forum/topics/colour-of-clothes)

> Sunday - Ruled by the sun.  The Lord is generally dressed in red
>   garment (ruby).
>
> Monday - Ruled by the moon.  Their Lordships wears white on this day,
>   the color of pearl.
>
> Tuesday -Ruled by the planet Mars. wears red or pink garments on this
>   day, the color of the coral.
>
> Wednesday - Ruled by Mercury. Lord wears green, the color of the
>   emerald.
>
> Thursday - Ruled by Jupiter. Lord wear yellow or gold dress, the color
>   of the yellow sapphire.
>
> Friday - Ruled by the planet Venus. Lord wears white garments this
>   day, the color of the diamond.
>
> Saturday - Ruled by the planet Saturn. Lords wears the black cloth on
>   this day, corresponding to the color of the blue sapphire.
>
> Generally in temples we do not strictly follow this routine, but on
>   special days like Ekadasi, the lord is dressed in Red or Pink Colour.
>
> On Purnima, white and Amavasya, Black or dark colors.

Comment: Thanks for this useful insight. This is very helpful. I didn't knew about this.

Comment: @AnkitTripathi Welcome! You can continue to use the site to enrich your knowledge. In general white color flowers clothes can be used for all deities when specific is not known or not mentioned.

Comment: Can you please tell, what should we do to the cloth after puja. Means in Satya Narayana katha we offer cloth to Lord Vishnu but after completion of Katha what should we do with the cloths. Flowers use to viserjit in river but what about cloth?

Comment: cloth also u can do visarjan or give to the poor