# Favourite colour of Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, krishna, gods, narasimha

I am planning to buy a Rose plant, I would love to know Maha Vishnu's favourite colour (Probably Krishna's and Narasimha's, as they are my ishta and kula devas), I would love to buy the rose colour which is dear to him, Is there any references in the Puranas/vedas regarding his favourite colour?

Comment: Rose may not be his favorite flower but yellow is possibly his favorite color.

Comment: Oh Is it mentioned that yellow is his favourite colour?

Comment: Widely in practice yellow is associated with Lord Vishnu . for exact Puranic sources you should wait for someone to answer .. see this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19165/4732

Comment: The 'kadambu' flower is associated with Mahavishnu. It is a yellowish-white colour. Yellow is the colour of his robes. There is another white flower called the 'nantyārvaṭṭam' offered to Mahavishnu.