# Favorite Color of Devi (Kali/Durga/Mansa)

Tags: devi, durga, shakti, shaktism, kali

Perusing topics on here and came across this thread discussing favorite color of Narayan for Vishnu-bhakt :

[Favourite colour of Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51320/favourite-colour-of-vishnu?r=SearchResults&s=35%7C15.8064)

Ideal to know for choosing which flowers for arpit and such, which hue of clothes to wear for days of puja or temple-visits, selecting which color cloth for small at-home altar/shrine etc

Looked up other topics of the same and found black color clothes often worn for ShaniDev, and his crow/vulture vahan is black too.

So wondering what color according to scripture would be auspicious for different forms of Durga & Kali ? (I know different colors are worn on different days for Navrathri.) Googling is bringing up lots of contradictory info as is often the case.

As a general rule would it be red, as you see ladies often wearing the white sari with red border for Durga Puja ?

Would like to know same for Mansa Devi also.

I’m assuming this might be slightly region-specific (or maybe not ?) As customs and riti for puja of the same deity sometimes seems to be so different for different places in India.

As far as choosing clothes color to wear, color of cloth for small home shrine, or puja flowers color, I know lots of this info is in different Tantra texts as they are sadhana-shastra, but I haven’t gotten hold of good translations yet. Any info greatly appreciated, thx ! :)

Edit : There are so many different forms of Devi that they probably all have different colors for puja rituals ? Bagalamukhi with yellow (for one of the MahaVidya) is one I am remembering off the top of my head.

In the question I linked the answer for Narayan was given as yellow in the comments, but maybe for Devi it will really depend on which form of Devi the puja/vrat etc is for.

Comment: Ma saraswati also like yellow/white

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Thx ! :)